# Field Extension equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K ⊆ L$ be an algebraic field extension and $u, v ∈ L$ with $[K(u) : K] = m$
and $[K(v) : K] = n$. Show that $[K(v)(u) : K(v)] = m \iff [K(u)(v) : K(u)] = n$,
and both equalities hold if $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know that I'm meant to use the product rule so that
[K(u,v):K(v)][K(v):K] = [K(u,v):K(u)][K(u):K] = [K(u,v):K]
but unsure on how to continue from here

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned you should use the Tower Law. You would get:

$$[K(v)(u):K] = [K(v)(u):K(v)][K(v):K] = [K(v)(u):K(v)]n$$

Also:

$$[K(v)(u):K] = [K(u)(v):K(u)][K(u):K] = [K(u)(v):K(u)]m$$

Hence:

$$[K(u)(v):K(u)]\cdot m = [K(v)(u):K(v)]\cdot n$$

From here you should be able to derive the conclusion

Comment: Would it be correct to say that we can derive that m=n from this equation?

Comment: @TylerStephens Not really. However you can derive that if $K(u)(v):K(u)] = m$, then we have $[K(u)(v):K] = mn$